# Are there any AppStudio for ArcGIS tutorials?

Tags: android, references, arcgis-appstudio

Any other documentation available regarding a detailed tutorial on how to use the new [beta 2 app studio](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/appstudio/).

I have trolled the Internet and found the minimal information docs on esri regarding the app studio but still need assistance.

Does anyone know where to locate some additional resources, or document the baseline process from a Web application to the final product app on an android?

Comment: Do you have an ESRI Developer Account?

Comment: Yes I do. I tried looking for resources there but nothing in level of detail I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

It is still a beta product and you won't be able to get more help that what you have already found.

You should log in into [Esri Early Adopter](https://earlyadopter.esri.com/home.html) web page (if you are enrolled); there you can find all the resources related to the product including documentation, known issues and useful video links.

The primary source of documentation for AppStudio can be found at http://doc.arcgis.com/en/appstudio/. There is a channel on YouTube called [AppStudioForArcGIS at Esri](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaDpuQi3gcd5YD9KW-_jsQg), there are some tutorial videos out there. One video on Esri Videos I found is [here](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/4274/appstudio-for-arcgis-beta-1-getting-started).